# Result Sources restriction when not logged in

Tags: search, search-results, query, result-source

I'd like to restrict some files when a user, who is not logged in, searches for files. Is that possible?

I tried building a query in **Result Sources -> "custom name" -> Query Transform**, where I can see the property *Account* and *AccountName* is available, but i can't see how I can put it to use in this context.